# How do I remove a space between an integer variable and a string in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
def print_scores(name1, score1, name2, score2):
     print("\n--- SCORES\t"+ name1 + ":",score1,"\t" + name2 + ":",score2, "---")


print_scores("Ziggy",18,"Elmer",23)
```

I am trying to remove the space between score1 and "\t". It does not change the output. But the program checking the work requires that there is no space between them in the code.

Comment: Welcome, this is your first question. May I suggest that you edit your post and start by explaining the problem, followed by everything you have already tried to resolve it and conclude with you expectation. Keep each question focused on a single problem and provide as much information as possible to attract attract a knowledgeable user with your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `format`, like this:

```
print('\n--- SCORES\t{}:{}\t{}:{}---'.format(name1, score1, name2, score2))
```

Now for `print_scores("Ziggy",18,"Elmer",23)`, it prints this:

`--- SCORES    Ziggy:18    Elmer:23---`

Comment: @MH472 you got it ^_^

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with the print builtin function.
By default it sets a keyword `sep = ' '`
This can be overridden by the use of:

```
print(..., sep='')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Python 3.7, this would work and will be the easiest way to format:

```py
def print_scores(name1, score1, name2, score2):
     print(f"\n--- SCORES\t{name1}:{score1}\t{name2}:{score2}---")


print_scores("Ziggy", 18, "Elmer", 23)
```